# Regression on Numerical Variable where NA is Present Using R

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

I am working on building a multivariable regression using a dataset in R. That dataset contains a variable that is generally an integer, but at times can have NA values. Because the NA values make sense for the dataset, I don't want to remove the observations entirely that have the NA values. However, I don't want those NA values considered for regression for that specific variable.

For example, credit scores in the USA are integers, but foreign nationals (non-USA residents) do not have a credit score, i.e., NA.

How would something like this be handled in R?

I have tried such things a `na.omit`, but they remove the entire observations.

Comment: I hope you find [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/optmatch/versions/0.9-10/topics/fill.NAs) helpful.